# Can we prevent guest accounts from viewing with whom else a file has been shared

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, external-sharing, guest-access

I have a sharepoint online site which is open to external sharing, and i want to share some files and folders with external users >> but i do not want the guest accounts to view the file permissions >> so they do not know with whom else the file has been shared? is this possible? or since a guest account can view the file content, then the guest account can also view its permission (with whom the file is been shared with)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to make guest users cannot see others else the file or the folder has been shared.

When you share a folder with some guests, guests will be able to see other's names in the manage access panel.